# How can I show $||v||^{2}_2 \leq ||v|_{1}| \cdot ||v||_{\infty}$ holds?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, numerical-methods

How can I show $||v||^{2}_{2} \leq ||v||_{1} \cdot ||v||_{\infty}$ holds? That is, for a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$,

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}|v_i|^{2} \leq \max_{i=1}^{n} |v_{i}| \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} |v_i|?$$

I have managed to prove the result that $||v||_{\infty} \leq ||v||_{2}$ holds; I don't know if that helps in any way. I was thinking of writing $||v||_1 \cdot ||v||_{\infty} \geq ||v||_{1} \cdot ||v||_{2}$, but I didn't get anywhere.

Comment: $$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}|v_i|^{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}|v_i||v_i|\le \sum_{i=1}^{n}\max_j\{|v_j|\}\times|v_i|
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly elaborating on @d.k.o.'s comment:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n | v_i |^2 &= \sum_{i=1}^n |v_i| |v_i| \\
\tag{1}&\leq \sum_{i=1}^n \| v \|_\infty | v_i | \\
&= \| v \|_\infty \sum_{i=1}^n |v_i| \\
&= \|v\|_\infty \|v\|_1.
\end{align}
In step (1) we used the fact that $| v_i | \leq \| v\|_\infty$.

Comment: Ahh ok. You can move it outside the sum because the max is independent of $i$. Got it